# How do I change the "alt activates the menu" feature of Windows 10 from a toggle to a hold?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

There is an accessibility feature in Windows where pressing the alt key will activate and focus the menu at the top of the screen.  The issue I'm having is that this feature is toggled with the alt key instead of only being active while the alt key is held down.

Currently, I use several applications that demand I hold down alt + the mouse do use some functionality, but then when I'm done the menu at the top is still toggled on.

Is there a way to change this in Windows 10 so that the menu is selected while I hold alt, and when I let go of alt the menu loses focus?

Comment: idk the answer, but in case you were googling solutions, the term for the  'opposite' of  a toggle switch is a momentary switch.